# solution to the ODE $y' = \frac{xy+\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}}{1-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

is there are a solution for this ODE?
$$y' = \frac{xy+\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}}{1-x^2}$$

Comment: @ Mohamed Perdu If you are interested to know if the ODE has at least a solution then here it is: $y(x)=-1$, for $x>1$.

Comment: @RobertZ , yes , that's the trivial solution, other one is $y(x)=1$ for $x<-1$ ,what I need is a more general solution (which includes those two as special cases).